# Stop a div sliding up if an element is visible

Tags: jquery, slideup

Ok so heres my problem:
I need the top div to only slide up/down when the **mediaPlayerWrapper** is there and not when the **content_text** is there.
both are created using Ajax and php and only one exists at a time.
As per my code bellow it works fine in the **mediaPlayerWrapper** but unfortunately it still slides in the **content_text**. any Ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#main_content").ajaxStop(function(){

        if ($("#content_text").length){ 
        }

        else if($("#mediaPlayerWrapper").length){// Slide top and bottom bars when video wrapper is displayed
            $("#top").slideUp(2000); //slide up(hide) DIV's


                var timer;

                $('html').mousemove(function(e) { //slide(show) DIV's down on mouse move
                    if(window.lastX !== e.clientX || window.lastY !== e.clientY){   //Check to see if mouse has moved before running code
                        $('#top').slideDown(2000);                      


                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(function(){
                                            $('#top').slideUp(2000)//<--- this is the line that is causing the problem
                                                }, 5000);//slide back up after 5 seconds
                        }

                        window.lastX = e.clientX //stores the current x coordinate
                        window.lastY = e.clientY // stores the current y coordinate
                    }); 
        }

    });
```

sorry I cannot provide a fiddle or link to the site.
    });

Answer (score 0):

Well if length isn't working right for you for some reason, you could always use '.addClass()' to add something like 'is_shown' and then check for it using '.hasClass('is_shown')'. Using this method you may need an additional parent/wrapper that isn't added or removed from the DOM with your ajax function.